# Mi script en php se ejecuta dos veces desde xampp

Tags: php, xampp

Tengo un script sencillo en php es cual solo ejecuta un query a la base de datos, pero resulta que se ejecuta dos veces, pensé que era la cache ya que cuando lo ejecuto desde el modo incognito (Chrome) y solo ejecuta una vez. Lo corro desde xampp. Quizá sea alguna configuración del apache.

```
class Conectar{
    public static function conexion(){
        $conexion=new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "alquiler");
        $conexion->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        return $conexion;
    }
}
$conexion = new Conectar();
$mysqli = $conexion->conexion();
$randon = rand();
$sql = "INSERT INTO correo (randon) values ('".$randon."')";
if($mysqli->query($sql)){
    echo $sql;
} else {
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
```

Comment: En el código no hay nada que pueda hacer que se ejecute dos veces, probablemente sea un bug de xampp o un error en la configuracion

Comment: Tienes alguna idea, ya que en modo incognito solo se ejecuta una vez

Comment: Es muy raro, prueba a ejecutar un script en el que ponga `echo "Prueba"` para ver si en ese caso en una ventana normal tambien se ejecuta dos veces, si es asi, es problema del servidor. Si no, es que hay algo raro en ese código (aunque yo no veo nada que pueda provocar ese problema)

Comment: lo acabo de solucionar, no se exactamente cual era el problema si era alguna extensión, cache algun virus al chrome, ya que si funcionaba bien en firefox e internet explorer. Lo que hice fue volver a instalar el chrome y solucionado

Answer (score -1):

A mi me paso algo similar, y si efectivamente era el navegador, pero eran las extensiones, alguna de ellas hacia que mandara